# Add ArrayList as parameter in VBA

Tags: vba, arraylist

I would like to add an `ArrayList` as parameter to a function. So far I have:

```
Function ThisFunction(parameter1 As ArrayList, parameter2 As Dictionary)
```

I created the `ArrayList` in the calling function with:

```
Dim parameter1 As Object
Set parameter1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Dim parameter2 As Object
Set parameter2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

I get `User-defined type not defined`.

How should I define this type?

Comment: You have to pass the parameter as `Variant` - there is no `ArrayList` in VBA

Comment: You need to add a Reference to mscorlib or use late binding (CreateObject("ArrayList")).  For the ArrayList class  declaring a reference to mscorlib  does not enable intellisense but will allow you to use ArrayList rather than object or variant in the parameter list.

Comment: The ``ArrayList`` object is already created. I edited the message. Would ``variant`` and ``object`` give the same result?

Comment: `parameter1 As Object`  - the same as your declaration in the calling code.